# Can someone explain why my question may have been downvoted?

Tags: discussion

I have followed the guidelines and made it clear what the problem is and what I have done and yet [my question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/150831/unable-to-disable-iptables-in-centos) [Domain Name problems in CentOS hosted under VirtualBox](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/150831/unable-to-disable-iptables-in-centos) has been downvoted. Can someone explain to me why?

Comment: Already did, click the My question link

Comment: My apologies, was hard to see the color change...

Comment: No problem at all

Answer (score 3):

<strike>So</strike> If you hover the mouse above the down arrow (V) next to the beginning of a question, you get to see "This question doesn't show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful".

I cannot see when the down-votes occurred, but from the state of your question (on the main site), at the time you asked your question here, IMHO any of those three reasons for down-voting, could have applied for a person having read through one of the initial five versions of your question.

My suggestion would be to **never** assume someone reads the title as part of the question text, and therefore always **first** state **in the text itself** what the problem was that you encountered, followed by what you did, and why you think that should have solved the issue and/or what went wrong. That way a reader is not left guessing what it is that you are trying to achieve, until after reading the complete question text, as was the case with the first version.

Comment: [A estimated timeline of the votes](http://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/150831/timeline)

Comment: @Braiam Interesting, but not providing enough detail on how the (down) votes interleave with edits up until 18:30 on the 18th. How did you get to the timeline from the original question? Is there a link on the Q page I missed?

Comment: It's one of the [unlinked](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76566/list-of-unlinked-pages-on-stack-exchange-sites) pages of SE.